# MLFlow run: Pass parameters in a file instead of key/value pairs

Tags: python, machine-learning, mlflow, mlops

Usually when running an MLProject, I would use something similar to:

```
mlflow run . -P alpha=0.1 -P l1_ratio=0.9
```

Is it possible to pass a file containing the key/value pairs instead ? so something like:

```
mlflow run . --file ./parametrs
```

where ./parameters contains the key/value pairs (like an env file or something)

One way I thought of is to make a seperate bash script that accept the file and extracts the key/value pairs to be included in the run command, but I wonder if there's a way more native to mlflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported functionality according to [documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-run), and [source code](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/cli.py#L124), so you'll need to add your own wrapper to read parameters from file & pass them explicitly.